# Resolve dependencies for mobilemediaconverter and monodevelop

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, libraries, monodevelop

I recently installed a video converter software and later I removed it.

After removing it, I can't seem to install any other software. It seems when I removed the video converter software, it also removed some library that is necessary for other software to be installed, too.

Now, I want to install monodevelop, but it again notifies so much dependencies!

Here is what my terminal says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install monodevelop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mobilemediaconverter:i386 : Depends: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.2.0)
                             Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.2.0)
                             Depends: mencoder:amd64
 monodevelop : Depends: gnome-icon-theme (>= 1.1.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: monodoc-manual (>= 1.1.9) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mono-runtime-sgen but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mono-xbuild but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgconf2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglade2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglib2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgnome-vfs2.0-cil (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgnome2.24-cil (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-cairo4.0-cil (>= 4.0.4.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil (>= 3.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-posix4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-data4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-web4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil (>= 4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.9) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: monodoc-base (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libglade2.0-cil-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libgtk2.0-cil-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: mono-devel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Please, can you give me any solution to the problem.

Comment: Have you done: `apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Not really a dupe of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the output from apt it says:

```
...Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:......
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
       This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
       to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
       specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
       is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
       system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
       so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
       using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
       Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

After that, I can suggest you try:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop
```

Apt will search for all dependencies related to `monodevelop`.

After that,

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Ultimately, you can check everything you're looking for with

```
sudo apt search packagename
```

To search repositories for packagename.

```
sudo apt show packagename
```

To show detailed description of the packagename.

You can simulate the apt-get process by using

```
sudo apt-get -s install packagename
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -s build-dep packagename
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
       No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on
       the current system state but do not actually change the system.
       Locking will be disabled (Debug::NoLocking) so the system state
       could change while apt-get is running. Simulations can also be
       executed by non-root users which might not have read access to all
       apt configuration distorting the simulation. A notice expressing
       this warning is also shown by default for non-root users
       (APT::Get::Show-User-Simulation-Note). Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::Simulate.
```

---

> "Now, I want to install monodevelop, but it again notifies so much
>   dependencies!"

Dependencies are usually a must, but sometimes can be omitted when they are referred to as Recommends.

From `man apt-get`

```
   --no-install-recommends
       Do not consider recommended packages as a dependency for
       installing. Configuration Item: APT::Install-Recommends.
```

Generally, it is good to `build-dep` then install package.

Get in the habit of using the man pages.

From shell type:

```
man command
```

and read.

Comment: thanks , I used this "apt-get -f install" as it is a duplicate question.. but thanks for the response